# Why do Images Loaded from Heroku Load Progressively

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, image, heroku, progressive

I have a small (Rails 3.1) app running on Heroku (with images also served from Heroku) The images load progressively (from top to bottom). If I take the same images and place them on another (Apache) server, they seemingly pop into existence once they are loaded.

So why are they loading top-to-bottom on Heroku? Is it just that they are loading really slowly (so the progressive download is obvious) or is it something to do with the way Heroku serves images?

Comment: My gut says that it is a 1 dyno issue; so your browser is only getting back 1 image at a time. If you increase your dyno count from 1 to 3, see if this fixes for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

which server are you running under heroku? Did you use a procfile and if not (and the app is using webrick) you could try thin or unicorn and see if that makes a difference and speeds things up. 
Example http://michaelvanrooijen.com/articles/2011/06/01-more-concurrency-on-a-single-heroku-dyno-with-the-new-celadon-cedar-stack/

Comment: Well fancy meeting you here ;) Thanks. That's a very interesting link. Will switch to Unicorn later and see if that helps. I'm imagining that moving my assets over to an S3 bucket is probably the answer.

Comment: A 4-process Unicorn setup made a difference, but ultimately offloading all the assets to S3 has all but solved it.